# Asp.net validator issue

Tags: asp.net

I am using a require field validator for a textbox in asp.net application. Problem is that when there is no value in textbox then no button on the web page do not works even page redirection button for back page also not performing function and validator gives err msg which i define
But if I put sum value in it then all btn works correctly.

Can anyone tell me that how can i overcome this problem

Answer (score 2):

Set the CausesValidation attribute to False on the button and link controls that don't require validation (such as your back button).

```
<asp:button id="btnBack" runat="server" causesvalidation="false"></asp:button>
```